# execute command from shell script fails

Tags: bash, rsync

When I run my script it fails:

```
# sh -x ./rsync.sh 
...
+ rsync --safe-links --password-file=/etc/rsync.secret -rtvun --include='*.log*.gz' --filter='-! */' --prune-empty-dirs /some/path foo@hostname::foo
Unknown filter rule: `'-!'
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at exclude.c(904) [client=3.1.1]
```

but when I copy&paste the `rsync --safe-links ....` line and execute it it works fine.

**rsync.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

rsync_opts="--safe-links --password-file=/etc/rsync.secret -rtvu"

while read path hostname volume extra_opts; do
  rsync ${rsync_opts} ${extra_opts} ${path} ${volume}@${hostname}::${volume}
done < /etc/rsync.paths
```

**rsync.paths:**

```
/some/path/ hostname foo --include='*.log*.gz' --filter='-! */' --prune-empty-dirs
```

Does anyone knows why it fails from the script and works fine when I run the command manually ? How can I fix it ?

**UPDATE:**
It works fine when I use `eval "rsync ..."` but still I don't know why it doesn't work withou it :/

Comment: I wasn't immediately able to find a good SO duplicate, but it's [this problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). The output of `sh -x` is ambiguous (`touch 'hello world'` and `touch hello  world` both output the same thing), leading you to think you execute the same command even though you don't. Use `bash -x` instead.

Comment: If this is an issue about bash misinterpreting the variables, shouldn't quoting them help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your script reads the text `--filter='-! */' --prune-empty-dirs` into the variable `$extra_opts`, which is passed literally to the command, including the apostrophes. So it is split into the following arguments: `--filter='-!`, `*/'` and `--prune-empty-dirs`. When you `eval` it though, then the whole line is passed to the shell interpreter which interprets the apostrophes the way you want, that's why it works.

Also, since your script uses `bash`, you should debug it with `bash -x` instead of `sh -x`.

Comment: So... could `echo rsync ${rsync_opts} ... |xargs` help? And if so, would that be safer then `eval`ing?

Comment: `xargs` won't help for the same reason the original command doesn't work. It still passes tue arguments literally. If you want to interpret a sting you got as an input as the shell would, your only option is `eval`. Alternatively you can put one argument in each line of the input file, but then you'll need a more complicated parser.